# How to pass list of arguments to method in R?

Tags: r, methods, arguments

I'm trying to pass arguments as a list to a method. I'm creating methods of stuff to pass to a data.frame. Example:

```
dfApply <- function(df, ...) {
  UseMethod("dfApply", df)
}

dfApply.sample <- function(df, size, ...) {
  # Stuff
  df <- sample_frac(df, size = size)
  return(df)
}
```

Now, if I call the function:

```
args <- list(size = 0.5)
class(df) <- c("sample", class(df))
df <- dfApply(df, args)
```

The method still receives it as a list().

Is there a way to pass arguments like this?

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comments, `do.call()` solves the problem (for now), but I have to define every argument in `args`:

```
args <- list(df = df, size = 0.5)
class(df) <- c("sample", class(df))
df <- do.call(dfApply, args)
```

Is this a wise way to implement methods? Doesn't seem right.

Comment: What code are you using to determine what class the function is receiving?

Comment: In general you can use `do.call` to pass arguments as a list to any function. See `?do.call`.

Comment: What were you expecting exactly? You are putting `args` in a list. But you assumed they would be removed from the list at some point? I'm not sure I understand. You want the list to be automatically expanded?

Comment: Here, I'm expliciting `class(df) <- c("sample", class(df))`, but in the code I have a list of characters that match the method names that I use to determine the class of the data.frame.

Comment: are you referring to `stats::df` or an object you have created called `df`

Comment: I say again _what_ _code_?

Comment: @MrFlick That's exactly what I want to know if is possible. I have a list of arguments and I want to pass them to the method, because I can't call them directly. If it isn't possible, I'll try another alternative.

Comment: @ngm Forgot about do.call. I'll see if it works somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @rawr sorry, object called df of class data.frame

Comment: Yes, `do.call()` and turn a list into function arguments. But be sure you are not abusing the S3 dispatch methods. The signatures can't change too much.

Comment: @42- It's a shiny app in which I have a `selectInput`. So I get the value in the `input$` variable and extract the name of the method from it.

Comment: @MrFlick Yeah, I guess if I use `do.call()` I'll have to drop using S3 methods. :(

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, apparently it works if I pass arguments in a vector (with `c()`), but unfortunately it's useless for me, since sometimes arguments aren't gonna be of the same class.